# get variable of combobox for sqllite query in tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, combobox

i have an issue that i want to query from combo box value selected from sqllite database and show in graph,here is my code.I will be appreciate any one could help me.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlite3
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,  
    NavigationToolbar2Tk) 


    def imprt_data():
      import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")],
                                               title = "Choose a file")
      df = pd.read_excel(import_file_path)
      return df

  def svetosql():
    df=imprt_data()
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///save_pandas.db', echo=True)
    sqlite_connection = engine.connect()
    sqlite_table="Data"
    df.to_sql(sqlite_table, sqlite_connection, if_exists='fail')
 def sqlconection():
    con=sqlite3.connect('save_pandas.db')
    c = con.cursor()
    return c

def callback_obj(event):
   comboobject=event.widget.get()
   return (comboobject)

def callback_rgn(event):
  comboregion=event.widget.get()
  return (comboregion)


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Testing Tkinter Combobox With Sqllite')
root.geometry('500x500')

  ##---------Widget---------------
  comboregion=ttk.Combobox(root,width=50 , height=20)
  c=sqlconection()
  for row in c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT  Data.شهرستان from data '):
    Query = [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()]
 comboregion['values']=Query
 comboregion.pack( ipadx=2, ipady=2 )
 selectvalueregion=comboregion.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback_rgn)
 #------------------------
 comboobject=ttk.Combobox(root,width=50 , height=20)
 c=sqlconection()
 for row in c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT    from Data '):
 Query = [member[0] for member in c.description]
 comboobject['values']=Query
 comboobject.pack( ipadx=2, ipady=2 )
 selectvalueobject=comboobject.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback_obj)

 for row in c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT  * from Data WHERE region LIKE ? ;' ,        (selectvalueobject,)):
   Q = [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()]
   print(Q)
   #------------------------
   f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=80)
   a = f.add_subplot(111)
 a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
 canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
 canvas.draw()
 canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(ipadx=2, ipady=2)


 root.mainloop()
```

the graph has some data only for show,but i want to get data from combo box and then make query from database and after that show in graph.
if any one want to get database ,please leave comments.

Comment: the columns are missed here : `SELECT DISTINCT    from Data`

Comment: that was  Data.region , i have no problem with this , notice me about query from selectvalueobject in my code

Comment: The indentation of your code is a mess. Please fix it, the code as posted can't run at all.